# Pairing Sphero with Windows 8

Tags: sphero-api

To make the dev process a bit more efficient, I"m seeking to pair Sphero with my PC.  My PC doesn't seem to find the device so that I can pair to it.  Does anyone have any advice for getting this to work or know that it won't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with the bluetooth drivers for the motherboard.  I updated the drivers for the ASUS Z87-PRO and can now see the Spheros device.